# Biztalk Getting 'NullPartException' error when using xpath

Tags: .net, biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-orchestrations

Profile: Biztalk 2009 update 4 on Windows 2008 Server SP2 (Development platform)
Hi When using xpath to map my output using a Message Construct and a Message Assignment with the following code:

```
    sXPath = System.String.Format("/*[local-name()='ProcessSalesOrder' and namespace-uri()='http://www.TestSchemas.net/TestSchemas_V2_2/schemas']/*[local-name()='header' and namespace-uri()='http://www.TestSchemas.net/TestSchemas_V2_2/schemas']/*[local-name()='detail' and namespace-uri()='http://www.TestSchemas.net/TestSchemas_V2_2/schemas' and position()={0}]", nLoopCount);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sXPath);
    SingleInput = xpath(Input, sXPath);
```

I get an Exception in the Event Viewer;

```
    Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 15
    Inner exception: The part 'part' of message 'SingleInput' contained a null value at the end of the construct block.

    Exception type: NullPartException
    Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.Engine
    Target Site: Void ConstructionCompleteEvent(Boolean)
```

I have a simple orchestration with one Receive Port one Send port using two schemas. I get the record count of the unbounded "detail" into a variable called `nRecordCount` and I am using a loop counter in the `MessageLoop` to increment this placed at the end in an Expression object with `nLoopCount = nLoopCount + 1;` as the expression.

[image: Orchestration]

The detail structure of the 2nd Schema (Name: SalesOrderDetail_V2_2.xsd) is the same as the 1st (Name: SalesOrderRequest_V2_2.xsd) but all the header tags removed.

[image]

and the SalesOrderRequest_V2_2.xsd below

[image]

It seems like a Square peg is trying to be mapped to a round hole. I have tried to debug this but fails at the following code in the file0.cs at the point shown below;

[image]

I cannot find anything useful in the Orchestration Debug either. 
Can anyone shed some further light on what I maybe missing when using Xpath?

The complete project has been zipped and is available to download at the following address

[*https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=533fd5a521c8c878&resid=533FD5A521C8C878!1848&parid=533FD5A521C8C878!119&authkey=!AE4gYqCoqmZd8xs*](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=533fd5a521c8c878&resid=533FD5A521C8C878!1848&parid=533FD5A521C8C878!119&authkey=!AE4gYqCoqmZd8xs)

Please see this link for a possible fix. I have managed to get a workable solution if I change the Schema Structure (XSD) file.

Here is the link:
[xpath - How to get Method B to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660330/xpath-how-to-get-method-b-to-work)

Comment: Hi Filburt, The reality is that the above project and structure works well with a simple XSD schema definition with only five elements under the detail node with no other header elements. If I increase the complexity of the XSD schemas as shown in the screen shots with many nodes and elements in the header node as well as the detail node, then I get the situation where it I get the exception error. As far as I can see the two schemas with the detail node are identical.

Comment: In debug, I can see the nRecordCount variable populated with the correct number of detail elements in the GetRecordCount Expression. It enters the MessageLoop but fails at the point where "SingleInput = xpath(Input, sXPath);" expression is executed. the SingleInput message is based on the SalesOrderDetail schema and sXPath is the result of the retrieval from the expression "System.String.Format("/*[local-name()='ProcessSalesOrder' and namespace.......".

Comment: I believe that there is some mismatch of using xpath function that I cannot solve using the complex schemas in this Orchestration version I have. It must be simple but I seem to be blind on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a very similar scenario (creating a batch of messages from a single input message) and ended up with only a slightly different solution:

Inside the loop I create a simple Counter message, assigning the current counter value.

Next inside a Construct Message shape I have a Map which uses the Counter message and the original source message as input messages and the batch message schema as the output.

Inside the Map I use a "Call Xslt Template" Script functiod which receives the counter value from the Counter Message as a Xslt param. This param I use to extract the desired source node with basically the same XPath (i.e. position()=$param) like you do.

I'm aware that using Call Xslt Template may not be an option for you simply due to the huge amount of fields.

I don't have my BizTalk dev environment ready atm but extracting the sequence node should also be possible using "plain" functoids instead of Call Xslt Template.